# styled-component - passing props best practices

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

Imagine a scenario like this: you create a theme and pass it to ThemeProvider.
It could look like this:

```js
const theme = {
   palette: {primary: {main: 'blue', contrastText: 'white'}, surface: 'gray'},
   borderWidth: '1px',
   shadowMixin: size => `0px 0px ${size} black`
}
```

Then you create a component:

```js
const Something = styled.div`
   color: ${props => props.theme.palette.primary.contrastText};
   background: ${({theme}) => theme.palette.surface};
   border: ${props => props.theme.borderWidth} solid ${({theme}) => theme.palette.primary.main};
   box-shadow: ${props => props.theme.shadowMixin('10px') };
`;
```

and well... it looks very messy. You can use object destruction, fake mixins or whatever, but it's hard to keep it clean when you keep passing functions in each line. I thought of doing something like this:

```js
const Something = styled.div`
  ${({ theme: { palette, borderWidth, shadowMixin } }) => {
    css`
       color: ${palette.primary.contrastText};
       background: ${palette.surface};
       border: ${borderWidth} solid ${palette.primary.main};
       box-shadow: ${ shadowMixin('10px') };
    `;
  }}
`;
```

but it's not perfect either.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I don't think documentation mentioned it, but apparently a syntax like this works too:

```js
const Something = styled.div(
  ({ theme: { palette, borderWidth, shadowMixin } }) => css`
       color: ${palette.primary.contrastText};
       background: ${palette.surface};
       border: ${borderWidth} solid ${palette.primary.main};
       box-shadow: ${ shadowMixin('10px') };
    `
);
```

It looks way better, and I don't think it can get any better than this.
But if you have some ideas feel free to share them.